# Kotlin send html code as a template via email intent

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin

I am trying to send html code (round 500rows / frontend) as part of a string with the given code below. But when i select email app, i see only *tags* and *jacascript/styles* etc in the beginning of the email, and at the bottom i see the *Texts*. I think it may be a problem with the styles or i am missing something.

```
 val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
    intent.type = "text/html"
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Template")
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,spannable)
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
        fromHtml(spannable.toString(), TO_HTML_PARAGRAPH_LINES_CONSECUTIVE)
    } else {
        fromHtml(spannable.toString()) // or for older api
    }
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Email"))
```

Would like some help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot send arbitrary HTML via `ACTION_SEND` through an email client. You will be limited by the capabilities of the email composer UI of the user's chosen email client. In particular, such a composer is unlikely to be able to handle any HTML that cannot be represented as `CharacterStyle` objects in an `EditText`. So, if you are using JavaScript, CSS, `<iframe>`, tables, and similar things, those are very unlikely to work for any given email client.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but despite that i have more than 2 days trying anything i have found but still seems a bit strange that in android cant do that. Tried exactly the same thing in iOS and it works successfully, and i thought i am missing something, or android system doesn't allows that, which seems to be confusing.

Comment: @cod-e-rection: It is not the "android system" so much as it is the nature of email apps and `ACTION_SEND`.

Comment: But as i stated it doesn't seem right that you can make it on iOS and not in android.

Comment: @cod-e-rection: There are many differences between those operating systems.